# Finding text in array Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, indexing

I have a code

```
require 'rubygems'
conf_array = []
File.open("C:/My Program Files/readme.txt", "r").each_line do |line|
conf_array << line.chop.split("\t")
end

a = conf_array.index{|s| s.include?("server =")}
puts a
```

and it doesn't display the index of item. Why?

Array looks like

```
conf_array = [
  ["# This file can be used to override the default puppet settings."],
  ["# See the following links for more details on what settings are available:"],
  ["# - docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/config_important_settings.html"],
  ["# - docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/config_about_settings.html"],
  ["# - docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/config_file_main.html"],
  ["# - docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/configuration.html"], ["[main]"],
  ["server = server.net.pl"],
  ["splay = true"],
  ["splaylimit = 1h"],
  ["wiatforcert = 30m"],
  ["http_connect_timeout = 2m"],
  ["http_read_timeout = 30m"],
  ["runinterval = 6h"],
  ["waitforcert = 30m"]
]
```

And next how to display that item? I mean `a = conf_array[#{a}]` says syntax error.

I tried also

```
new_array = []
new_array = conf_array.select! {|s| s.include?("server =")}
```

and it again does't display found item. Any suggestion?

Comment: "ruby" is one of your tags, as it should be. It's redundant to have "Ruby" in the question's title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perfect use case for [`Enumerable#grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep)

```
File.open("C:/My Program Files/readme.txt", "r")
    .each_line
    # no need to .flat_map { |l| l.split(/\t/) }
    .grep /server =/
#⇒  ["server = server.net.pl"]
```

Comment: That works. Is there any posisbility to prevent finding text e.g. "sn_server ="?

Comment: `Enumerable#grep` accepts a regular expression. Pass `/^server = /` to lookup for `server` in the beginning of the line etc. The margins are too small to explain how regexps work in details.

Comment: In notepad++ anything I write after /^server = / doesn't work. Why?

Comment: OK, I found File.open("C:/My Program Files/readme.txt", "r").each_line.grep(/server =/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't call `String#include?`, but `Array#include?` :

```
["server = something.pl"].include?('server = ')
# false
"server = something.pl".include?('server = ')
# true
```

Remove the `split("\t")`.

To read the file into an array, you can just use :

```
conf_array = File.readlines("C:/My Program Files/readme.txt")
```

or

```
conf_array = File.readlines("C:/My Program Files/readme.txt").map(&:chomp)
```